Difference between kubectl apply -f calico.yaml and kubectl create -f tigera-operator.yaml with custom-resources.yaml?
I question from a newbie in kubernetes. When creating a kube cluster, there is the phase where we create the network pods, and I have found, so far, two ways to do that :

This way


kubectl create -f
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.28.1/manifests/tigera-operator.yaml
kubectl create -f
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.28.1/manifests/custom-resources.yaml


And this one


kubectl apply -f
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.28.1/manifests/calico.yaml

What is the difference between them?
Regards.

@ Wodel Did you have time to check my Answer?Does it help to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.

kubectl create-f and kubectl apply-f  are  deploying calico in your k8s cluster is how it handles existing resources.
When you run kubectl create-f with a yaml file, the command tries to create all resources as defined in that file. It will do this by creating tigera-operator.yaml and custom-resources.yaml.
Kubectl apply-f uses only one yaml named calico.yaml which combines both tigera-operator.yaml and custom -resources.yaml into one.
It’s completely up to you if you want to install network policies, calico resources or any other kubernetes resource in your cluster.
